# Import data retrieved from API into Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

First, what I can do and am not looking for help with: I am able to create all the requisite custom post types, taxonomies etc. and I am also able to use the API calls to retrieve all required information.  I am not including API details to avoid getting sidetracked.

I simply need an example of using a search box inside a 'Add New' post to get results and select a single result from that search then how to use that selection to modify the post title and attach a picture/media to the post prior to publishing.

I've seen it done on sites but have not found a plugin or code that I might reference. I know it is possible but it is a fairly specific need that I have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: I don't fully understand, can you post a screenshot of which search/add new do you mean?

Comment: I saw a video with a similar function that I am still trying to locate.  Example of what I want to do:  While in "Add New" search Youtube for videos, select a video from the list returned, use information about the video to populate tags, title, description prior to publish (so them may be edited).  Rather than have user go to Youtube, copy, paste, etc. be able see results from inside the "Add New" screen.  Does that help?

Comment: Maybe http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/insights/ ?